# What's the difference between document and object (Map)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the firebase's docs mention we can't store document inside document .

But I was trying to store object inside document and then i get all power of document.

#### Question :

I was wondering what the difference between document and object (map) is.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A document is a concept in Cloud Firestore that represents a unit of data that's indexed in a collection.  It is not a data type.  Its contents are retrieved as a DocumentSnapshot type object, and the fields and values in the document are represented as a Map in Java.

An object is a type of field in a document.  Its contents are also represented as a Map in Java.  Other types of fields are integer, double, arrays, timestamp, etc.

Comment: then  object inside collection called document and object inside document called map, is it true ?

Comment: A map is a collection of key-value pairs. A document is a contain for the metadata and data of an addressable entity in Cloud Firestore. A document's data is a map, and can contain nested maps.

Comment: The documentation doesn't refer to a document as an "object", but if it helps you think about it better, then that's up to you.